# How to manage cache in e-shop in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, e-commerce

I would like to implement cache in my system, but **firstly** I wonder how to manage, for example, list of products in e-shop, when there is option to change currency? Currencies do not have separated URLs (they're solved by cookies), like language translations which have its URL, so the same URL of the products list is for all currencies.

**Secondly**. Usually, in e-shop header, there is a cart icon with actual state of cart - how many products is inserted and its price, for example. Whole header could be cached, but this element. What is the simplest way how to solve this issue?

**Thirdly**. In e-shop, there is a lot of pages I can not imagine how to cache them, because they are very dynamic and/or use $_POSTs, for example, but maybe it is possible - for example, page with forms, searching or cart summarization where user fill his personal info, shipping, payment and so on. Is here a way how to cache even those pages or they should be excluded from caching?

I've tried to find some "tutorial" and basic informations how to manage caching in e-shops, but I did not find anything usefull.
I will appraise all new informations. Maybe some of my questinos are stupid, sorry about that.

*Just to be sure, I am not trying to find any framework which already has all these issues solved, but trying to understand how this works.*

Comment: POSTs should not be cached at all. You will save yourself many headaches ant it will help you to better architecture if you decide not to cache POSTs. The reason is, that the meaning of POST is to *change*. Therefore result of post is always 'new' or 'different' and therefore should not be cached because of the very nature of HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Most caching are done by by a cache key. Like `Cache::put('product-id-43', $product);`. So as long as you kan make a unique identifier then you can cache it.

### Caching a whole page

For cache by URL and a cookie value you can do something like this: `$key = 'url-'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'-'.$_COOKIE['currency']`. To use this cache you need to find a spot as early as possible in your code where you make a check to see if that key is cached. If it is just print it and exit, if it doesen't generate the page, add it to the cache and print the content.

### Partially caching

The principle is the same as before but instead of caching the whole page you just cache parts of it and then combining it. So in a simplified way, assuming header and footer is cached `echo Cache::get('header') . getCart() . Cache::get('footer')`. The trick to do this is to find the proper place to add this. Template engines might help with this.

### Caching POST

It can be done the same way a with the whole page, just add the method to the key. E.g. `$key = 'url-'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'-'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'-'.$_COOKIE['currency']`. The thing with POST is that they are supposed to change things and therefore often shouldn't be cached. This is the whole issue with cache, it's easy to cache stuff, the hard thing is to know when to invalidate the cache.

If you want to know more about caching I'll recommend checking out varnish. Is much much faster and way more flexible. One of the nice thing is that you can add more keys to an object, so if you tag all the pages with the currency then you can ban all pages with a specific currency if you change exchange rates etc. For the partial caching you can use server side includes.